# Updating Permissions and Profiles through Visual Studio Code

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, visualstudiocode

I am new to VS Code and trying to copy Permission Set permissions into a Profile so that we don't have too many permission sets. I thought rather than checking in SF and clicking back and forth I can do it from here. Im thinking I can copy the permissions from the permission set and then paste it into the profile and update it from VS Code.

This permission set doesn't tell me what permissions it has (see below)
[image]

This permission set on the other hand does.

[image]

Why does one show me what permission it has and the other one doesn't?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The first Permission Set does not permission any components.

If in your org this Permission Set actually does provide permissions, your local copy of the metadata may be out of date.

Unlike Profiles, retrieving Permission Sets does pull the entire component regardless of what other metadata is included in the manifest. That Permission Set is just empty.

Comment: Took the words right out of my answer box .

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend before doing the copy paste, to do a retrieve of the Profiles & Permission Sets.

But bare in mind that if you do it from the VS Code interface, with right click on the folder and retrieve, this wont download the FLS.

[image]

It's better to go to CLI and run something like this

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject,Profile,PermissionSet
```

That way while retrieving the custom objects and fields it will also get the Profile & Permission Sets with the Object & Field Security